Django CloudinaryField: Setting Default Privacy on Upload and Generating Presigned URLs for Public Access
I'm working on a Django project where I have a model Media with an image field stored using CloudinaryField.
Currently, I'm able to upload images via multipart/form, and I can generate a public link using media_object.image.url. However, I'm facing two challenges:

Default Upload Privacy: How can I set the default privacy of the uploaded images to be private?

Generating Presigned URLs: I need to generate presigned URLs for public access to these images, but I want these URLs to expire after a certain period, say 5 minutes.


Here's what my current model looks like:
from django.db import models
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

class Media(models.Model):
    # Other fields...
    image = CloudinaryField('document', null=True, blank=True)

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve these two objectives? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!


You can create an upload preset which sets the delivery type to private and make this the default for for Media library/API uploads as per cloudinary.com/documentation/dam_admin_upload_presets
To generate URLs that expire after some time, you need to use the token/cookie-based auth but this is a premium feature and only available on Advanced or higher plans, more here https://cloudinary.com/documentation/control_access_to_media#token_based_authentication_premium_feature. You can still use delivery type authenticated which means all URLs will need to be accessed via a signed URL but this does not expire, more here https://cloudinary.com/documentation/control_access_to_media#authenticated_media_assets

